# How do I get a local install of google.appengine.ext ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to use ndb to write some data to google datastore.  My test set-up uses google datastore but local python programs.  I have installed the google cloud sdk and the datastore sdk, but I am still getting import errors. Should I be installing something else?

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class dsObj(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

The resulting error message is:

```
File /... line 10, in <module>
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

Comment: Can you confirm if you have installed the gcloud appengine component using this command `gcloud components install app-engine-python`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Cloud SDK dev_appserver.py to run the application?
Please refer to [Creating a Guestbook Application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/creating-guestbook)

Assuming that you are using App Engine Standard environment. [Storing Data in Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/storing-data-datastore) shows the required usage.